# Ember.js - Construct a href url in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to add a link that is dynamically generated in the template by appending a base url to a user id i.e I need something like 'http://google.com/?user_id=123'. How do I go about appending the base url to the user id in the href.

I need something that achieves the below result

```
<a href="base_url + {{user.id}}"> Visit User </a>
```

Comment: Have you gone through the guides the describe dynamic segments and query params? I just get the feeling that you are unfamiliar with ember. You normally dont create hrefs directly. Ember has a link-to helper for that.

Comment: I actually solved this using handlebar helpers right after I posted this. I could not get this to work with `bindAttr` or the `linkTo` helper or the `action` control. I know there is probably a way to do this in Ember. I'm not using Ember Data models either which offers some solutions. I'm revisiting Ember again after a couple of months and seem to have forgotten how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This problem doesn't require a Helper. You could do the following:

```
<a href="http://google.com/?user_id={{user.id}}"> Visit User </a>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It tries to add a script tag which basically invalidates the DOM.

Comment: Why would it try to add a script tag? Assuming the above anchor is in a compiled Handlebars template, and `user.id` is being passed into it correctly, there is not reason it shouldn't work. See this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/beC4X/](http://jsfiddle.net/beC4X/)

Comment: Handlebars works differently when used with Ember. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with creating a Handlebars helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('dynamicLink', function (username, id, label) {

    var link = '<a target="_blank" href="http://xxxxxx'+
    id + '/?username=' + username +'">' + label + '</a>';
    return new Em.Handlebars.SafeString(link);
});
```

and then this in the templates

```
{{dynamicLink user.username 1 "XXXX"}}
```